# accessing characters of urdu script

Tags: python, python-2.x, urdu

I have following string

```
test="ن گ ب ن د ی ک ر و ا ن "
```

what I want is that I want to access each character and save it in some variables for future access but when I looped over them I got weird output.Actually I am not aware of encoding schemes that much.

```
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

above code gave me some weird characters what I want is the original script characters?

Comment: Does the console you print to support these characters? Here on my Ubunut it works fine. How is your Python file encoded?

Comment: Do you use Python 3 or Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either define `test` as a unicode string, or use the `decode` method:

```
test="ن گ ب ن د ی ک ر و ا ن"
for i in test.decode('utf8'):
    print(i)
    # print unicode value
    print(repr(i))

test=u"ن گ ب ن د ی ک ر و ا ن"
for i in test:
    print(i)
    # print unicode value
    print(repr(i))
```

Obviously my answer concerns Python 2.7.x.

Comment: @FullName yes but then its code would not print weird characters

Comment: The code from the question copied and pasted into an interactive Python 3 session on a terminal that supports Unicode works without any problem. So the question is incomplete.

Comment: @Frodon Your first code snipped used in Python 3 throws `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

Comment: @FullName yes, that's why it is written `Obviously my answer concerns Python 2.x`

Comment: `print(i)` is not Python 2. The question is unclear.

Comment: @Frodon Please also tell me how to get the unicode of the corresponding character?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed change `print(i)` by `print(repr(i))`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.x try this:

```
test=u"ن گ ب ن د ی ک ر و ا ن "
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

Appending `u` makes it a `unicode` object.

Comment: Why are you sure he is using Python 2.x?

Comment: I am not which is the reason why I edited the answer.